# perform selector on the running CCScene from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a `GameScene` and a CCMenu in that scene which 1st calls `[self pauseSchedulerAndActions]` and then pops up an alert. The alert has it's own class.

What i want is that when i press on Resume in the alert the scheduled selectors and actions to resume ( aka to call `[self resumeSchedulerAndActions]`).

The problem is that everything i do doesn't seem to work.

What i've tried:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene]resumeSchedulerAndActions];
```

which should return the current scene (GameScene) and then perform the selector..but it doesn't

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler]resumeTarget:[GameScene node]];
```

am i missing something...or doing it wrong...or what?

Comment: What does [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] return? What do you mean when you said it doesn't seem to work? Are you getting an error, a crash, or what?

Comment: runningScene reuturns the correct scene but doesn't perform the selector. And it doesn't crash or anything..just doesn't resume selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..fixed the problem

what i did is this:

-added `self.tag=111;` in the init method of `GameScene`

-made a instance method in GameScene that resumes the selectors

-in the popup menu i called the method like this :

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene]getChildByTag:111]performSelector:@selector(resumeGame)];
```